# hacer busqueda de un dato de una tabla a otra y imprimir

Tags: java, algoritmos, java-8

Buenas a todos bien tengo dos listas que llamo de una base de datos de distintas tablas:

```
listat = personNE.list();
listah = historicot2NE.list();   

        int inter1 = listat.size(); // 81 datos
        int inter2 = listah.size(); // 18 datos
```

lo que quiero hacer la listah donde esta  asegurados compare con la listat que son todas las persona e imprima los que están asegurados y los que no esta asegurados hice esos 2 bucles pero estoy mal

```
for (int i = 0; i < inter2; i++) {
            if (listah.get(i).getCODIGO() == listat.get(i).getCODIGO()) {
                pw.println(String.valueOf(listat.get(i).getCODIGO_DOC()
                        + "|" + listat.get(i).getCEDULA() + "|" + "0" + "|"
                        + "1" + "|" + "|" + 1 + "|"));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < inter2; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < inter1; j++) {
                if (listah.get(i).getCODIGO() == listat.get(j).getCODIGO()) {
                    pw.println(String.valueOf(listat.get(i).getCODIGO_DOC()
                        + "|" + listat.get(i).getCEDULA() + "|" + "0" + "|"
                        + "1" + "|" + "|" + 1 + "|"));

                }

            }
```

Espero su ayuda gracias de antemano.

Comment: La primer version del for no sirve para lo que queres. La segunda se parece bastante y muestra todos los asegurados no? te faltaria el resto?

Comment: si faltaría el resto que seria 63 que no estén entre los 81 de la listat pero no me sale con ninguno de los 2 for

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Siguiendo solamente tu logica, vamos a invertir los for, y mostrar si y solo si, no encuentro listat en listah.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inter1; i++) { //iteramos sobre listat
    bool Encontre = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < inter2; j++) { //iteramos sobre listah
        if (listat.get(i).getCODIGO() == listah.get(j).getCODIGO()) {
            Encontre = true;
        }
    }
    if (!Encontre) { //si no lo encontre, no esta 
        pw.println(String.valueOf(listat.get(i).getCODIGO_DOC()
                        + "|" + listat.get(i).getCEDULA() + "|" + "0" + "|"
                        + "1" + "|" + "|" + 1 + "|"));
    }
}
```

Que estamos haciendo? lo mismo que hiciste antes, pero con la diferencia que las vueltas las damos con las listas cambiadas. Y tenemos una variable encontre, que si encuentra un item de los dos lados, evita que imprima sobre el item que estoy iterando.

Comment: Gracias lo estoy probando solo que ahora no me vota nada me diste una idea ver cual parte falle en mi for

Comment: hay algo que se esta obviando por que no me vota los qu son false